# Create custom command object with command specific attributes

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Id like to create a custom command type i guess you'd call it. the idea is every time the command is called it first checks its custom attribute then modifies that same attribute.

here is the code i have so far, though it doesn't work i hope it demonstrates what im trying to do.

```
class Perc(commands.Command):
    def __init__(self , func , basePrice = 10):
        super().__init__(func)
        self.basePrice : int = basePrice
        
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # modify base price
        self.basePrice += 10
        return await super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        
@Perc(basePrice = 25)
async def testPerc(ctx : commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("command called")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the factory function that returns the new class. To decorate a function, you need `@decorator(args)` which does `(decorator(args))(func)`. This is why `__call__` does not work.

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/core.py), at line 498, you have `__call__(self, context: Context[BotT], /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:`. You can see that this is not the creation of a decorator, but rather actually calling the object.

There is a better way to do this, using [`before_invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.before_invoke).

```py
@dataclass
class Perc:
    basePrice: int


price = Perc(basePrice=25)

@commands.command(name='perc')
async def perc(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'I have finished the command: {price}.')

async def before_perc(ctx):
    price.basePrice += 10
    await ctx.send('I have finished before_invoke')

perc.before_invoke(before_perc)
client.add_command(perc)
```

This makes `before_perc` execute right before executing the command. This is where you can add your logic such as increasing the base price.

Output (ran twice):
[image: out]

Comment: Why not use a decorator for `before_invoke`?

Comment: Interesting. I tried that but it refused to work, so I just did it the normal way.